# Transform object in another one, manually

Tags: object, kotlin, transformation

I have the next method:

```
fun get(browsePlayerContext: BrowsePlayerContext):  Single<List<Conference>>
```

Which returns a Single> with the next structure for the Conference object:

```
data class Conference(
        val label: String,
        val uid: UID?,
        val action: BrowsePlayerAction?,
        val image: String
)
```

But I need to transfor this response in a:

```
Single<List<EntityBrowse>>
```

The entity browse has the same structure I mean:

```
data class EntityBrowse(
        val label: String,
        val uid: UID?,
        val action: BrowsePlayerAction?,
        val image: String
)
```

I am doing the transformation manually, but I need a more sophisticated way, because I am gona get different kind of objects and I will have to do the same transformation to EntityBrowse.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do - if you're converting several objects, you'll likely have to convert it to a shared data format rather than using objects for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the .map function to transform the Conference objects into EntityBrowse objects

```
val conferences: List<Conference> = getConferences()

val entities: List<Entities> = conferences.map {conference -> 
 EntityBrowse(conference.label, conference.uid, conference.action, conference.image) 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function on `Single` object to transform `Single<List<Conference>>` to `Single<List<EntityBrowse>>`:

```
val result: Single<List<EntityBrowse>> = get(context).map { conferences: List<Conference> ->
    // transform List<Conference> to List<EntityBrowse> using `conferences` variable

    conferences.map { EntityBrowse(it.label, it.uid, it.action, it.image) }
}
```